# returning an array in JavaScript returns [object] instead?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to return two arrays(multiple values) through declaring them as objects

```
<script>
    function funWithArrays(arr) {

        const arr1 = []; //short string
        const arr2 = []; //long string

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].length <= 3) {
                arr1.push(arr[i]);
            } else {
                arr2.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return {
            arr1,
            arr2
        };

    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = funWithArrays(["we", "cream", "to", "this", "two"]);

</script>
```

This is my attempt to do so, however, when I go to run it the output is as follows:

```
[object Object]
```

I'm wondering why the actual arrays aren't being returned?

Comment: You're not returning an array, you're returning a non-array object with the properties `arr1` and `arr2` (those props refer to arrays). Then you're implicitly converting that object to string by assigning it to `innerHTML`, which triggers the default `toString` for objects (since yours doesn't define one), which for plain objects returns the string `"[object Object]"`. If you wanted to return an array of arrays, it would be `return [arr1, arr2];` (square brackets), which would convert to a string containing the string version of the array elements (but a bit confusingly, for nested arrays).

Comment: By "confusingly," I mean: The array `[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]` converts to the string `"1,2,3,4,5,6"` (which is exactly what `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` would convert to).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning incorrectly.

replace `return {arr1, arr2}` with `return [...arr1, ...arr2]` to return a single array.

Wrapping arrays in curly brackets( **{ }** ) convert them into an object. Since you need to return an array, wrap your arrays in square brackets( **[ ]** ) instead.

documentation for [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: oh okay thankyou

Comment: um I dont know if I can ask this but this was part of a practice question for my exams part of it was asking for this "the function should return an object which has two properties both arrays and named as arr1 and arr2, respectively" is this still correct?

Comment: @user16973340 - Your original code was doing what that sentence requests; the code above does not. So it may just be that you need to format your output, not change your return value. For instance, you could show the result as JSON: `.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(funWithArrays(/*...*/));` (but that's just one possible way you could format it).